# Why is homebrew postgresql not starting?

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

I am trying to start postgresql on m1 mac via `brew services start postgresql`.  However `brew services list` indicates that `postgresql`'s status is `error`.  Logs show:

```
2023-03-30 20:58:29.938 EDT [7593] LOG:  database system is shut down
2023-03-30 20:58:39.988 EDT [7608] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.7 (Homebrew) on aarch64-apple-darwin22.1.0, compiled by Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202), 64-bit
2023-03-30 20:58:39.990 EDT [7608] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432
2023-03-30 20:58:39.990 EDT [7608] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2023-03-30 20:58:39.990 EDT [7608] LOG:  could not bind Unix address "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432": Address already in use
2023-03-30 20:58:39.990 EDT [7608] HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432?
2023-03-30 20:58:39.990 EDT [7608] WARNING:  could not create Unix-domain socket in directory "/tmp"
2023-03-30 20:58:39.990 EDT [7608] FATAL:  could not create any Unix-domain sockets
2023-03-30 20:58:39.991 EDT [7608] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

I have deleted the lockfile at `/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock` already.

I have confirmed that nothing is running on port 5432 via `sudo lsof -i :5432`.

I've executed `sudo killall postgres` as well.

1. why does brew services think the "address" is "already in use?"
2. why can't I `create Unix-domain socket in directory "/tmp"`?

Comment: Seems another postgres is already running on the same port. Either find it using `ps` and kill or run yours on an other port

Answer (score 1):

I had to delete both `/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432` and `/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock`